# Controlling the data partition in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Data Looks Like:

col 1 col 2 col 3 col 4 
row 1 row 1 row 1 row 1 
row 2 row 2 row 2 row 2 
row 3 row 3 row 3 row 3 
row 4 row 4 row 4 row 4 
row 5 row 5 row 5 row 5 
row 6 row 6 row 6 row 6

Problem: I want to partition this data, lets say row 1 and row 2 will be processed as one partition, row 3 and row 4 as another, row 5 and row 6 as another and create a JSON data merging them together with the column (column headers with data values in rows).

Output should be like:
[ 

{col1:row1,col2:row1:col3:row1:col4:row1},

{col1:row2,col2:row2:col3:row2:col4:row2},

{col1:row3,col2:row3:col3:row3:col4:row3},

{col1:row4,col2:row4:col3:row4:col4:row4},...

]

I tried using repartion(num) available in spark but it is not exactly partitioning as i want. therefore the JSON data generated is not valid. i had issue with why my program was taking same time for processing the data even though i was using different number of cores which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556654/spark-streaming-same-processing-time-for-4-cores-and-16-cores-why) and the repartition suggestion was suggested by @Patrick McGloin . The code mentioned in that problem is something i am trying to do.

Comment: I don't think you mean `partition` because you can generate your JSON from a single RDD without particular concern for partitioning. If you know the array position that your keys need to be applied to, you can use scala's `zip` in an RDD `map` call.

Comment: I have used the zip feature to combine header with row to create json data but incoming data is microbatch and has around 10000 rows. It requires processing in less than 10 mins because of which i need to use more partitions to use  more cores. If i use single rdd without partitioning it the task takes around 45 minutes which is not acceptable as incoming data comes every 10 minutes.

Comment: If you just need evenly-sized partitions then `repartition` should get you what you want. Make sure you have enough workers/executors in your cluster to utilise your cores otherwise the partitions will run sequentially anyway. On the other hand, if you need to process a particular subset of the rows together, then I agree with @Lukasz Tracewski below, but you may be able to use `groupByKey` which would be simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess what you need is *partitionBy*. In Scala you can provide to it a custom build HashParitioner, while in Python you pass *partitionFunc*. There is a number of examples out there in Scala, so let me briefly explain the Python flavour.

*partitionFunc* expects a tuple, with first element being the key. Lets assume you organise your data in the following fashion:
(ROW_ID, (A,B,C,..)) where ROW_ID = [1,2,3,...,k]. You can always add ROW_ID and remove it afterwards.

To get a new partition every two rows:

```
rdd.partitionBy(numPartitions = int(rdd.count() / 2),
                partitionFunc = lambda key: int(key / 2)
```

*partitionFunc* will produce a sequence 0,0,1,1,2,2,... This number will be a number of partition to which given row will belong.

Comment: or a `groupByKey` solution might do too.