# Broadcast Variables not showing inside Partitions Apache Spark

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Scenario and Problem: 
I want to add two attributes to JSON object based on the look up table values and insert the JSON to Mongo DB. I have broadcast variable which holds look up table. However, i am not being able to access it inside foreachPartition as you can see in the code. It does not give me any error but simply does not display anything. Also, because of it i cant insert JSON to Mongo DB. I cant find any explanation to this behaviour. Any explanation or work around to make it work is much appreciated.

Here is my full code:

```
object ProcessMicroBatchStreams {
val calculateDistance = udf { 
 (lat: String, lon: String) =>      
 GeoHash.getDistance(lat.toDouble, lon.toDouble) }
 val DB_NAME = "IRT"
 val COLLECTION_NAME = "sensordata"
 val records = Array[String]()

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  if (args.length < 0) {
  System.err.println("Usage: ProcessMicroBatchStreams <master> <input_directory>")
  System.exit(1)
}
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setMaster("local[*]")
  .setAppName(this.getClass.getCanonicalName)
  .set("spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs", "false")
/*.set("spark.executor.instances", "3")
.set("spark.executor.memory", "18g")
.set("spark.executor.cores", "9")
.set("spark.task.cpus", "1")
.set("spark.driver.memory", "10g")*/

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(60))
val sqc = new SQLContext(sc)
val gpsLookUpTable = MapInput.cacheMappingTables(sc, sqc).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2)
val broadcastTable = sc.broadcast(gpsLookUpTable)


ssc.textFileStream("hdfs://localhost:9000/inputDirectory/")
  .foreachRDD { rdd =>
  //broadcastTable.value.show() // I can access broadcast value here
  if (!rdd.partitions.isEmpty) {
    val partitionedRDD = rdd.repartition(4)
    partitionedRDD.foreachPartition {
      partition =>
        println("Inside Partition")
        broadcastTable.value.show() // I cannot access broadcast value here
        partition.foreach {
          row =>
            val items = row.split("\n")
            items.foreach { item =>
              val mongoColl = MongoClient()(DB_NAME)(COLLECTION_NAME)
              val jsonObject = new JSONObject(item)
              val latitude = jsonObject.getDouble(Constants.LATITUDE)
              val longitude = jsonObject.getDouble(Constants.LONGITUDE)

              // The broadcast value is not being shown here
              // However, there is no error shown
              // I cannot insert the value into Mongo DB
              val selectedRow = broadcastTable.value
                .filter("geoCode LIKE '" + GeoHash.subString(latitude, longitude) + "%'")
                .withColumn("Distance", calculateDistance(col("Lat"), col("Lon")))
                .orderBy("Distance")
                .select(Constants.TRACK_KM, Constants.TRACK_NAME).take(1)
              if (selectedRow.length != 0) {
                jsonObject.put(Constants.TRACK_KM, selectedRow(0).get(0))
                jsonObject.put(Constants.TRACK_NAME, selectedRow(0).get(1))
              }
              else {
                jsonObject.put(Constants.TRACK_KM, "NULL")
                jsonObject.put(Constants.TRACK_NAME, "NULL")
              }
              val record = JSON.parse(jsonObject.toString()).asInstanceOf[DBObject]
              mongoColl.insert(record)
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
sys.addShutdownHook {
  ssc.stop(true, true)
}

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
}
}
```

Comment: Where does `MapInput` come from and what is the type of `gpsLookUpTable`?

Comment: i have a file GPSLOOKUPTABLE.json which is a look up table. MapInput Fucntion returns the Dataframe using SparkSQL of that table.   Function is:                  `def cacheMappingTables(sc: SparkContext, sqlContext: SQLContext): DataFrame = {
    val allRows = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/supportFiles/GeoHashLookUpTable")
    sqlContext.read.json(allRows).registerTempTable("GeoHashLookUpTable")
    val gpsLookUpTable = sqlContext.sql(" SELECT Lat, Lon, geoCode, TrackKM, TrackCode, TrackName, SubTrackCode, SubTrackName  FROM GeoHashLookUpTable ")
    return gpsLookUpTable
  }`

Comment: @Patrick McGloin your insights please

Comment: @Erik Schmiegelow your insights please

Comment: I am still stuck here. Anyone has the answer on how can i parallelize the processing and access the broadcast variable as well?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to broadcast an RDD.  Try something like this:

```
broadCastVal = gpsLookUpTable.collect
broadCastTable = sc.broadcast(broadCastVal)
```

You should be able to get the value you're expecting.

Comment: i am trying to do some select operation on broadcast value `val selectedRow = broadcastTable.value
                .filter("geoCode LIKE '" + GeoHash.subString(latitude, longitude) + "%'")
                .withColumn("Distance", calculateDistance(col("Lat"), col("Lon")))
                .orderBy("Distance")
                .select(Constants.TRACK_KM, Constants.TRACK_NAME).take(1)` in the code and using collect returns array and i wont be able to do it. I was wondering what is causing the issue. Before i did repartition i was able to access the values using the same way. Any Ideas?

Comment: I was messing around on the spark shell, and found this out.  When you use broadCastTable.value, its returning a memory address, and then scala figures out how to print it.  You can check this by adding the following line to your code
    `println(broadCastTable.value)`
If you try to grab a certain index of the broadcast variable, it will return the value
     `println(broadCastTable.value[1])`

Not sure how helpful that was, but hopefully its pushing you in the right direction and you can possibly hack together something that will solve your problem

Comment: i am not sure how you did it but i can't access the index of broadcast variable as you have mentioned `println(broadCastTable.value[1])`. Firstly, there was an error while accessing the index so i changed `println(broadCastTable.value[1])` to `println(broadCastTable.value(1))` but the problem is it can't take Int value as input so i changed again to `println(broadCastTable.value("1"))` but it turned out it was trying to access the column and the value passed was column name. Even though i supplied column name, i still cant retrieve the value. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Ahh dumb mistake on my part.  You definitely need the () and not the [] for scala.  The reason I could pass (1) in is because I was using an array.  I'm stumped on your issue.  I suppose you could always just skip the broadcast part and join the rdds as opposed to looking up the value in the broadcast table.  Not sure how much data or what your sla is, but that could be an alternative.  I'll watch this as I'm curious to what ends up happening now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure about this but after two encounters as such i am writing this answer. I could broadcast a RDD but i am not able to access the value. If i create a list or treeMap, i am being able to broadcast and retrieve the value as well. I am not sure why. Although, i haven't found any where written that we cant broadcast a RDD.